# Hide ASSIGN A QUEUE without disabling phone icon

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

We wanted to hide/remove the ASSIGN A QUEUE on flex dial pad but it also disables the blue phone icon and it requires agent press enter on keyboard after entering phone number. Is it possible to hide queues section while having the phone icon clickable?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

css file with below code worked.

```html
.Twilio-OutboundDialerPanel-QueueSelect-Caption {
    display: none;
}
.Twilio-OutboundDialerPanel-QueueSelect {
    display: none !important;
}
```